# Garbage characters while converting results into xml in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

Garbage characters are comming while converting my table results into xml

Following is the sql code which i am using

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl
(
RowID INT
, Comments NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

-------------------------------


INSERT INTO #Tbl(RowID, Comments) VALUES (1, '&test 123123123 & test
test123&
' )
INSERT INTO #Tbl(RowID, Comments) VALUES (2, '&test 123123123 & test' )
INSERT INTO #Tbl(RowID, Comments) VALUES (3, '&test 123123123 & test
test123&
&&' )

------------------------------------


SELECT  
    (
        SELECT distinct  
            RowId       

            ,Comments AS Comments
        FROM  
            #tbl AS t
        FOR XML RAW, TYPE
    )FOR XML PATH('Table'), TYPE


------------------------------------

DROP TABLE #tbl
```

Can anyone help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you think are garbage characters are not garbage but perfectly formed entity-encoded characters, allowing the literal ampersands and line breaks in your comments to be included.in the XML.

Comment: @ChrisDickson thanks for comments, Can you please help me how i can remove these characters.

Comment: @Asif, don't know exactly what you mean... In short: You cannot remove them! There are certain characters which are **not allowed** within an XML. But this is only a technical issue. In all cases the XML should be shown to the user after some kind of transformation. There you'll get the "original" text back.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, they are not garbage characters, they act more like escape characters.

Width that being said, for your purpose, do a replace

```
SELECT ( SELECT distinct RowId ,    REPLACE(Comments, '&amp;', '&') AS Comments 
        FROM #tbl AS t 
        FOR XML RAW, TYPE )
        FOR XML PATH('Table'), TYPE
```